# Problema en el envio de formulario a correo personal

Tags: php, html, formularios

Estoy creando una página web en la cual tengo un formulario creado en *HTML* y una página en *PHP* para enviar los datos a mi correo. El código *HTML* y *PHP* va correctamente, pero no me llega el correo con el formulario a mi *gmail*, que es una cuenta personal.

Adjunto el código *HTML* y *PHP*. Son pruebas para una página web personal.

*HTML*:

```html
<section class="site-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-4">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1>Contactanos</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row blog-entries">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8 main-content">
            
            <form action="send_email.php" method="post"><a target="_blank">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                      <label for="name">Nombre</label>
                      <input type="text" name="name"id="name" class="form-control ">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                      <label for="lastname">Apellidos</label>
                      <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="form-control ">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                      <label for="phone">Telefono de contacto</label>
                      <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control ">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                      <label for="email">Correo electronico</label>
                      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control ">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                      <label for="message">Escriba su mensaje</label>
                      <textarea name="message" name="message" id="message" class="form-control " cols="30" rows="8"></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                      <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary"></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
```

*PHP*:

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    // 
    $email_to = "miemail@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "Contacto desde Web";
    function died($error) {
        // mensajes de error
        echo "Lo sentimos, hubo un error en sus datos y el formulario no puede ser enviado en este momento. ";
        echo "Detalle de los errores.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Porfavor corrija estos errores e inténtelo de nuevo.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }
    // Se valida que los campos del formulairo estén llenos
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['lastname']) ||
        !isset($_POST['phone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['message'])) {
        die('Lo sentimos pero parece haber un problema con los datos enviados.');
    }

 //En esta parte el valor "name"  sirve para crear las variables que recolectaran la información de cada campo
    $name = $_POST['name']; // requerido
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname']; // requerido
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // requerido
    $telephone = $_POST['phone']; // requerido 
    $message = $_POST['message']; // requerido
    $error_message = "";//Linea numero 52;
//En esta parte se verifica que la dirección de correo sea válida 
   $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'La dirección de correo proporcionada no es válida.<br />';
  }
//En esta parte se valida el numero de telefono
  $number_exp = "/^[0-9]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($number_exp,$telephone)) {
    $error_message .= 'El numero de telefono introducido no es valido.<br />'; 
  }
//En esta parte se validan las cadenas de texto
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
    $error_message .= 'El formato del nombre no es válido<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$lastname)) {
    $error_message .= 'el formato del apellido no es válido.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($message) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'El formato del texto no es válido.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    die($error_message);
  }

//Este es el cuerpo del mensaje tal y como llegará al correo
    $email_message = "Contenido del Mensaje.\n\n";
    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }
    $email_message .= "Nombre: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Apellido: ".clean_string($lastname)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Teléfono: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Mensaje: ".clean_string($message)."\n";

//Se crean los encabezados del correo
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n";
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

?>
<!-- Mensaje de que fue enviado-->
Gracias! Nos pondremos en contacto contigo a la brevedad
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Revisaste si no están llegando a la carpeta Spam?

Comment: Se requiere configurar un host que es el que va a enviar el correo electrónico mediante SMTP. Puedes crear alguna cuenta de correo electrónico que sea la que va a estar enviando los emails utilizando la libreria de [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) o configurar un servidor local desde XAMPP para que esta pueda realizar los envíos.

Comment: No no llega a ningun lado....lo he mirado en spam y nada

Comment: Buenas Paulo, estoy trabajando con XAMPP pero no se lo que dices de configurar el servidor para realizar los envios...Vi por foros que si ponia en php.ini el correo a enviar(el mio personal) me lo ejecutaba pero no hace nada de nada y nose que hacer al respecto, es al unica prueba que realice...

Comment: Compara tu configuración con lo que se indica en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18185233/5587982). Si no está así debes ponerla de ese modo, reinicia el servidor e intenta de nuevo.

Comment: Aquí hay un [tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/php-mail.html) que puede servirte para las configuraciones. Otra cosa es que cuando llamas a la función de mail le colocas un **@** antes no se sí tenía alguna razón esto. Y si no te funciona el tutorial entonces deberías utilizar PHPMailer tiene ejemplos para varios proveedores de correos electrónicos.

Comment: Hola Buenas chicos ya lo solucione tenia que quitar del codigo php @ antes del email como dijo Paulo y añadir las configuraciones en el archivo php.ini y sendmail.ini segun mis preferencias. Muchas Gracias a todos y si alguien necesita las configuraciones o el codigo que me avise un saludo y muchas gracias por las ayudas